# Can multiple stored procedures share one database-reading index?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have several stored procs, which iterate over a database, and i'd like to make sure that, between all of the procedures, each database record will be read exactly once.

so, if there are multiple clients concurrently calling the same proc, (or several of the different procs) no two clients are ever going to see the same database record as each other.

i haven't found anything, yet, that can do this for sql server. is there a way to share a reader, or other method for achieving my goal?

Comment: Are you looking to do some sort of locking?  What does it matter if two or more clients are reading the same record?

Comment: yes, and i quote: " each database record will be read exactly once" and "no two clients are ever going to see the same database record as each other" ;P

Comment: That doesn't explain why it matters though.  Since you are looking for locking, you want to add [transaction levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) to your stored procedures

Comment: @TTeeple do you have an example of using transaction levels to achieve this?

Comment: What are the clients?  Real or just jobs?  When I hear the work iterate, I think cursor = slow when dealing with large tables.  Part of what you are asking sounds like row level locking, which sql server does not support out of the box.  Without any more information, I am just guessing.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish?  For instance, two different people on the planet might do a search and get the first page of results as the same.  This would violate your idea!